# Anchor tag not appending within paragraph tag javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

//console.log(results[i].vicinity);
para = document.createElement('p');
aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"/restaurants");
aTag.innerHTML = results[i].name;
mypara = para.appendChild(aTag);
console.log(mypara);
nearby_places.appendChild(mypara); 

}
```

`console.log(mypara)` in the second last line creates `anchor tag` but that is not wrapped in paragraph tag as it should be according to code logic . what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You've logged `mypara`, what the log says?

Comment: it give `<a href=""> mytext </a>`

Comment: Jep, there's no `p`. You still have to append `para`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild`  returns the child back try consoling the the parent node `para` - `console.log(para);` to see the result of the append, The last line will look like this :

`nearby_places.appendChild(para);`

Comment: tell more specifically that what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 1):

The `appendChild()` method modifies `para` directly, rather than leaving the original intact and returning a modified value. So, you should continue to use your `para` variable for the paragraph, rather than `mypara`. Your modified code would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

//console.log(results[i].vicinity);
para = document.createElement('p');
aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"/restaurants");
aTag.innerHTML = results[i].name;
para.appendChild(aTag);
nearby_places.appendChild(para); 

}
```

More info: according to MDN, `appendChild()` returns the appended node. That's why your `console.log()` call was just showing the `<a>` tag. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample fiddle that works:
https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/22007/

```
para = document.createElement('p');
aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"/restaurants");
aTag.innerHTML = "wendys";
para.appendChild(aTag);
document.body.appendChild(para);
```